# jQuery - How to use parents() to access both 1 and 2 levels up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parents

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="vertical-tabs-pane">
   <div class="vertical-tab-navigation">
       <a class="previous-tab" title="Go back to previous step" href="#">Back</a>
       <a class="next-tab" title="Continue to next step" href="#">Next</a>
   </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="vertical-tabs-pane">
   <div class="vertical-tab-navigation">
       <a class="previous-tab" title="Go back to previous step" href="#">Back</a>
       <a class="next-tab" title="Continue to next step" href="#">Next</a>
   </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="vertical-tabs-pane">
   <div>
      <fieldset id="multistep-group_attendees" class="group-attendees">
          <div class="vertical-tab-navigation">
            <a class="previous-tab" title="Go back to previous step" href="#">Back</a>
            <a class="next-tab" title="Continue to next step" href="#">Next</a>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>   
</fieldset>
```

So: 3 vertical-tabs-pane fieldsets, each with a navigation div in the bottom.  But the 3rd set of nav is nested two levels deeper than the rest.

jQuery like so:

```
$(".next-tab").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane').hide().next('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane').show();
    return false;
});

$(".previous-tab").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane').hide().prev('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane').show();
    return false;
});
```

This works perfectly for the first two fieldsets; clicking 'back' and 'next' swaps you over to the next fieldset.  But it doesn't work for the 3rd set, even though it seems to me it should still traverse up the tree to the appropriate parental fieldset.

What do I need to change?  I am fine with having special functions `$("#multistep-group-attendees .next-tab")`  for the 3rd fieldset if that makes it easier.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried closest method - http://api.jquery.com/closest/?

Comment: Just doing a straight swap ("parents" to "closest") makes none of the nav work at all.

Comment: Can you post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), that reproduces your problem? `closest()` **should** work, I'm a little confused that it doesn't.

Comment: Oh I really want to get a demo that reproduces my issue.  I am apparently baffled by fiddle, though.  I can't make anything that works OR anything that doesn't.  Crap.

Comment: BAH even parents() works fine in the fiddle! There must be something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be with the `parents` method, but with the `next` and `prev` ones. These methods do not cycle (try [the demo](http://api.jquery.com/prev)). If there's no previous element, `prev` won't select the last one, and `next` works the same way.

Comment: That part should be OK -- there's other code [I tried to simplify for posting here] that only makes back/next show up when they should:  no "back" on first tab, no "next" on last tab.  Also these are only 3 of many tabs (and located in the middle) so there are both next/prev tabs for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it

```
$(".next-tab").click(function() {
    var current = $(this).closest('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane');
    var next = current.next('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane');
    if (! next.length ) next = current.siblings(':first');
    current.hide();
    next.show();
    return false;
});

$(".previous-tab").click(function() {
    var current = $(this).closest('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane');
    var prev= current.prev('fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane');
    if (! prev.length ) prev = current.siblings(':last');
    current.hide();
    prev.show();
    return false;
});
```

Using `closest()` and checking for next/previous existence seems to do the trick..

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VbgDg/